# Flowtype error. Object type is incompatible with string

Tags: javascript, flowtype

I wrote a small Javascript class that has an argument which accepts either a string or an object. However, I get this error:

```
Error: utils/HttpError.js:8
  8:    message:string | ErrorObj
                         ^^^^^^^^ object type. This type is incompatible with
512:     message: string;
                  ^^^^^^ string. See lib: /private/tmp/flow/flowlib_33322c59/core.js:512
```

I've tried not using the type alias, and simplifying the ErrorObj to just `{}`, but I've had no luck. Is this a bug, or am I missing something? I'm using flow-bin ^0.51.0. My class is below.

```
//@flow
"use strict";

type ErrorObj = {[key:string]:Array<string>}

class HttpError extends Error {
    status:number
    message:string | ErrorObj
    constructor(status:number, message: string | ErrorObj){
        super();
        this.status = status;
        this.message = message;
    }

    toString():string{
        return `status: ${this.status} message: ${JSON.stringify(this.message)}`;
    }
}

module.exports = HttpError;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The internal definition of `Error`](https://github.com/facebook/flow/blob/v0.50.0/lib/core.js#L507) has the `message` member variable typed as simply a string. Even after subclassing, the base class (`Error`) still might interact with `this.message` in some way. If you were able to redefine it to be anything other than a string, and it attempted to call `length` or `concat` or some other member of the `String` class, it would fail. Therefore you cannot override member types of subclasses.

You could instead try something like:

```
type ErrorObj = {[key:string]:Array<string>}

class HttpError extends Error {
    status:number
    _customMessage:string | ErrorObj
    constructor(status:number, message: string | ErrorObj){
        super(typeof message === 'string' ? message : null);
        this.status = status;
        this._customMessage = message;
    }

    toString():string{
        return `status: ${this.status} message: ${JSON.stringify(this._customMessage)}`;
    }
}
```

Comment: I did this `super(JSON.stringify(message));` in the constructor. Same idea.